# Is there a security risk in exposing the MongoDB url to the public?

Tags: mongodb, security

When I create a connection to MongoDB, I do something like this:

```
mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(
  () => { console.log("Successfully connected to", uri },
  err => { console.log("Could not connect to database" }
);
```

Is it dangerous to expose this information on the console? Could someone trying to hack into my site/database use this maliciously and if so, how?

Comment: Is your database accessible over the public internet‽ Then chances are you’ve already been “hacked”…

Comment: Did you enable authentication?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - no authentication

Comment: Very bad, in this case you should not make it public. Secure the database with authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One claims a system is secure if it cares about the Confidentiality, Integrity and Accessibility (so called CIA triad) of the **information** in transport, at rest and in processing. So, to judge whether a system is secure or insecure – we need to know what information it deals with.

If you put sensitive data into the database and expose it to the public, it is insecure, as Confidentiality is not provided.

You could argue that the DB holds only public information and that the Confidentiality is not an issue here. Ok, then what about the Integrity? Can everyone change the information in the database? Probably you could make the information read-only which would be a nice workaround over the Integrity issues, else the system is considered not secure.

Last thing last – Availability. It is an uncommon thing to expose the database to the public. One of many issues to deal with are Denial-of-Service (DoS) attacks. Exposed database raises the risk of someone running self-made queries intended to put big load on CPU/memory/bandwidth and leading to an outage. If this is not an issue here than yes, the system is secure.